how to calculate max,min,count,stdev,percentile of each column for a dataset in bigquery where the number of columns are more than 100?
how to calculate max, min, count, standard deviation, percentile of each column for a dataset in big query where the number of columns are more than 100 with 1.45 million records?
I tried with the below code which kept giving syntax error
DECLARE done INT64 DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE column_name STRING;
DECLARE column_names ARRAY<STRING>;

-- Get all column names from the table
SET column_names = (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(column_name)
  FROM `your_project.your_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
  WHERE table_name = 'your_table_name'
);

-- Initialize temporary table to store statistics
CREATE TEMP TABLE column_stats (
  column_name STRING,
  max_value FLOAT64,
  min_value FLOAT64,
  mean_value FLOAT64,
  count_value INT64
);

-- Loop over each column name and calculate statistics
FOR column_name IN (SELECT column_name FROM UNNEST(column_names))
DO
  INSERT INTO column_stats
  SELECT 
    column_name,
    MAX(CAST(column_name AS FLOAT64)) AS max_value,
    MIN(CAST(column_name AS FLOAT64)) AS min_value,
    AVG(CAST(column_name AS FLOAT64)) AS mean_value,
    COUNT(column_name) AS count_value
  FROM `your_project.your_dataset.your_table_name`;
END FOR;

SELECT * FROM column_stats;


Use below approach
SELECT *
FROM ML.DESCRIBE_DATA(
  TABLE `your_project.your_dataset.your_table_name`,
  STRUCT(5 AS num_quantiles, 3 AS top_k)
);   

see details about ML.DESCRIBE_DATA
